# Enumerating open windows from a Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows, service

I would like to enumerate child windows of a given process to check for dialog windows. For reasons I won't go into here, if it finds any, I'd like to subsequently kill that application.

Running a standalone application to do this works without any issues. The application has access (via some P/Invoke calls) to a process's windows and I can subsequently kill that application.

Running the same code as a service, however, does not work as expected. It seems that the user  running the service is not able to interact with the desktop (which is a setting I can only see for the LOCAL system account).

Does anyone know of any workarounds to this? Is it possible for me to enumerate a process's windows from a windows service?

FYI -- the code (at least an adaptation of) I'm using is available here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1405088/2115261

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably running Windows 7 (or 8 or Vista), because the ability for Windows Servcies to interact with the desktop was last supported in Windows XP.

There is a [white paper on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463353.aspx) that describes the changes made for Vista and upwards. Basically, it is now not possible to interact with the desktop in any way.

However, there is [an example on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/110568/Alternative-way-for-Window-services-to-interact-wi) that demonstrates how to interact with the Task Scheduler from a Windows Service, and the process executed by the Task Scheduler *can* interact with the desktop. Perhaps this would be a suitable workaround for you.

Comment: "Service Isolation" is the name of this behaviour. (helps finding articles when googling).

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at this. I should have mentioned - yes, I'm using Windows 7 Enterprise

Comment: @trilson - ok, good luck. I think it's your only hope - even if you could get the desktop window, you probably couldn't kill other processes anyway.

Comment: Killing processes works a treat (there are several scenarios which result in a process being killed), it's just this one scenario I can't seem to get right. Alas!

Comment: @Roger - All of the scenarios are evaluated from the same service -- killing seems OK so far, but maybe I've just been lucky (or maybe because the user running the service is the same as the user running the processes I'm monitoring?).

Comment: There shouldn't be any problems with killing a process from a service, provided the service is running with the appropriate rights.  You don't have to be in the same session as a target process to kill it.

Comment: I'm doubtful about that example, because it doesn't seem to specify the target session in any way.  My guess is that it will only work as written if the user account the service is running in is the same user account that is logged in interactively.

Comment: ... although I now see that the OP is doing exactly that. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can only enumerate windows on the same terminal services session (aka Remote Desktop session) as your process.  However, given appropriate privilege, you can launch a subprocess in another terminal services session to do the work on your behalf, although you need to be aware of the potential security issues depending on how you do this.

Assuming that you've already got a handle to the target process, the simplest approach would be to use `OpenProcessToken` to get a token in the target session, `DuplicateTokenEx` to duplicate it, and `CreateProcessAsUser` to launch the subprocess.  Since all you need is a yes/no answer, you can use the process exit code rather than needing an IPC mechanism.

Security implications: since your subprocess is running in the user's context, a knowledgeable user could prevent it from running properly.  Also, if you do use an IPC mechanism, you'd have to treat the input from the subprocess as untrusted (check for buffer overruns, etc.).

An alternative approach would be to launch a subprocess in your own context but in the target session.  IIRC, you can do this by duplicating your own token and using `SetTokenInformation` on the duplicate to change `TokenSessionId` before launching the subprocess with `CreateProcessAsUser`.

Security implications: the subprocess, and through it the service process and the service account, could be subject to shatter attacks (malicious window messages) and other risks, although the integrity level mechanism may mitigate this to some extent.  It is my understanding that creating a separate window station and desktop (with appropriate ACLs) eliminates these risks, but I'm not sure offhand of the impact on the code you want to run.  Another mitigation would be to use `CreateRestrictedToken` to remove all groups and privileges from the token before launching the subprocess.

Unless it is absolutely essential that the user not be able to subvert your ability to detect the existence of the dialog window, I strongly recommend the first approach.

Comment: This is very interesting; thanks for the input. I should have noted a few more things in my original post:

- The processes I (may) want to kill are kicked off automatically by a process scheduler called Autosys (i.e. there isn't necessarily an interactive session in progress)

- The processes and the service are running as the same user.

- The processes are trusted.

Comment: In principle, then, you could attach your service process to the same workstation and desktop as Autosys and do the work without a subprocess.  You might still get into trouble if the Autosys process exits and restarts for any reason, or if it deliberately launches the scheduled processes into separate workstations or desktops.

Comment: Couldn't you avoid the need for a separate monitoring service altogether by getting Autosys to launch a monitoring process that itself launches the target process?

Answer (score 0):

If you give the service a local system account to log on with, you will be able to tick the "Allow service to interact with desktop" checkbox in the service's properties (from Service Control Manager).

See the "Log On" tab of the Service's Property Pages.

That might work for you. But unfortunately, it probably won't. Still worth a quick try?

Comment: I thought about this, but unfortunately I really need to run the service as a specific user. A bit of a side-note, but the user running the service should be the same as the user that launched the process I'm inspecting.

Comment: I think if you are using a user account, it *does* enable that checkbox. But see Roger's answer - it probably won't work even if you can tick the checkbox. :(